# Ajax call in wordpress not working for subscriber user in front site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, permission-denied, admin-ajax

i have simple wordpress form to add data in custom table in wordpress using Ajax

my jquery code(Ajax code )

```
jQuery.ajax(ajax_object.ajax_url, {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: data,
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        alert(response);

                                    },
                                    error: function (error) {
                                        if (typeof console === "object") {
                                            console.log(error);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    complete: function () {
                                    }
                                });
```

my php code to save data

```
 if(!class_exists('bookly_appo_Ajax')) 
    {
        class bookly_appo_Ajax
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
            }
            public function init()
            {
                add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_booklyapp' );

                function enqueue_ajax_booklyapp($hook) {

                wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script-booklyapp', plugins_url( '/ajax.js?v='.rand(), __FILE__ ), array('jquery')); 
                wp_localize_script('ajax-script-booklyapp', 'ajax_object',
                        array(
                            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
                            )
                        );
            }

            add_action('wp_ajax_add_category_bookly', 'add_category_bookly_callback');
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_category_bookly', 'add_category_bookly_callback');
            function add_category_bookly_callback() {
                      $storeid=$_REQUEST['storeid'];

              $rows = $wpdb->insert(
                            $table_category, array(

                                'store_id' => $storeid,
                                 )
                            );
            $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
            }
      }
   }
}
```

my question is

1. when login with admin user  my ajax work fine but when login with other
   user(subscriber user) of my site it's give error "Opps!You do not
   have sufficient perissions to access this page"
2. which type of
   accessibility provide to subscriber to used admin-ajax.php file

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be you're not defining the action for privileged and non-priviliged users. Do you have both

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ACTION', 'bookly_appo_Ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION', 'bookly_appo_Ajax' );
```

In your php? `wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION` is probably what you're missing.